# Python OpenCV stereo camera position

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, stereo-3d

I'd like to determine the position and orientation of a stereo camera relative to its previous position in world coordinates. I'm using a bumblebee XB3 camera and the motion between stereo pairs is on the order of a couple feet.

Would this be on the correct track?

1. Obtain rectified image for each pair
2. Detect/match feature points rectified images
3. Compute Fundamental Matrix
4. Compute Essential Matrix

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Sounds like your on the right track. But, a couple of Q's: What about calibration of the cameras w.r.t one another (i.e. are you assuming this has already been done)?, What about calibration of both cameras to the world (i.e. are you assuming any initial known object in shot around which you move - with know dimensions and/or markers)? What are you hoping to gain from performing this in a stereo context (i.e. are you wanting a greater degree of accuracy by also exploiting depth)?

Comment: Fundamentally, are you interested in *relative* motion from some arbitrary initial position (e.g. the camera moved [dx,dy,dz]), or *absolute* motion within a known world-coordinate frame (e.g. if you have a model of the world to hand and the camera is now at [x,y,z])?

Comment: Good questions, I'll try my best to answer given my limited experience with CV terms and practices. Second question first as it may be most relevant. I'd really like absolute motion as what I'm trying to achieve is a outdoor mobile mapping system, by coupling GPS (when its known to be good) and using visual odometery(?) when GPS is bad. I had assumed the cameras (stereo pair) had already been calibrated with respect to one another by the manufacturer, or are you referring to the 'pairs of cameras'? If the second, then I didn't know this would be required.

Comment: Realized I may not have answered all that would help you to help me! The reason for stereo context was that in my original implementation of the system, I could easily gain georeferenced (world) point cloud data (one of my desired deliverables). However, I had naively assumed the resultant data from each stereo pair would be fairly well aligned simply by mechanical means of how I oriented the camera to my track. Now that I know a little more I realized I can do way better by incorporating some CV methods. So my system has a stereo camera because I didn't know any better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it sounds like you have a fair understanding of what you want to do! Having a pre-calibrated stereo camera (like the Bumblebee) will then deliver up point-cloud data when you need it - but it also sounds like you basically want to also use the *same* images to perform visual odometry (certainly the correct term) and provide absolute orientation from a last known GPS position, when the GPS breaks down.

First things first - I wonder if you've had a look at the literature for some more ideas: As ever, it's often just about knowing what to google for. The whole idea of "sensor fusion" for navigation - especially in built up areas where GPS is lost - has prompted a whole body of research. So perhaps the following (intersecting) areas of research might be helpful to you:

- [Navigation in 'urban canyons'](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=navigation%20in%20urban%20canyons)
- [Structure-from-motion for navigation](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=structure%20from%20motion%20for%20navigation)
- [SLAM](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=simultaneous%20localization%20and%20navigation)
- [Ego-motion](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=ego-motion)

Issues you are going to encounter with all these methods include:

- Handling static vs. dynamic scenes (i.e. ones that change purely based on the camera motion - c.f. others that change as a result of independent motion occurring in the scene: trees moving, cars driving past, etc.).
- Relating amount of visual motion to real-world motion (the other form of "calibration" I referred to - are objects small or far away? This is where the stereo information could prove extremely handy, as we will see...)
- Factorisation/optimisation of the problem - especially with handling accumulated error along the path of the camera over time and with outlier features (all the tricks of the trade: bundle adjustment, ransac, etc.)

So, anyway, pragmatically speaking, you want to do this in python (via the OpenCV bindings)?

If you are using OpenCV 2.4 the (combined C/C++ and Python) new API documentation is [here](http://docs.opencv.org/).

As a starting point I would suggest looking at the following sample:

```
/OpenCV-2.4.2/samples/python2/lk_homography.py
```

Which provides a nice instance of basic ego-motion estimation from optic flow using the function [cv2.findHomography](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#findhomography).

Of course, this homography *H* only applies if the points are co-planar (i.e. lying on the same plane under the same projective transform - so it'll work on videos of nice flat roads). BUT - by the same principal we could use the Fundamental matrix F to represent motion in epipolar geometry instead. This can be calculated by the very similar function [cv2.findFundamentalMat](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#findfundamentalmat).

Ultimately, as you correctly specify above in your question, you want the Essential matrix E - since this is the one that operates in actual physical coordinates (not just mapping between pixels along epipoles). I always think of the Fundamental matrix as a generalisation of the Essential matrix by which the (inessential) knowledge of the camera *intrinsic* calibration (K) is omitted, and vise versa.

Thus, the relationships can be formally expressed as:

```
E =  K'^T F K
```

So, you'll need to know something of your stereo camera calibration K after all! See the famous Hartley & Zisserman [book](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/hzbook/hzbook2/HZepipolar.pdf) for more info.

You could then, for example, use the function [cv2.decomposeProjectionMatrix](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#decomposeprojectionmatrix) to decompose the Essential matrix and recover your R orientation and t displacement.

Hope this helps! One final word of warning: this is by no means a "solved problem" for the complexities of real world data - hence the ongoing research!

Comment: Excellent response Tim, just what I was hoping for plus some!

Comment: I picked up the Hartley & Zisserman book the other day as well as the one by Szeliski to try and get a broader understanding. A follow up about the mysterious intrinsic parameters (K). It seems that in my case I have a camera f = 801.408020 (pixels), ppX = 324.561127 and ppY = 240.855042 (these extracted using the Point Grey libraries). So could my (K) be written as ([801.408020,0,324.561127],[0,801.408020,240.855042],[0,0,1])?

Comment: Great that you got the book. Working out K by hand is a little bit perilous for real-world cameras. Your working above looks OK - but is is assuming a "pin-hole" camera model with those exact parameters. Real cameras have optical systems that require much more sophisticated models to accommodate distortions and other effects. The only way to really work out you camera intrinsics is to calibrate with a model that can effectively describe the optical and imaging system. This isn't too hard, just have a look at the OpenCV functions based on calibration with a checkerboard pattern.